# update multiple rows in one query but the input we are expecting is from json object of multiple data

Tags: json, postgresql, jpa, arraylist

```
    update users as u set -- postgres FTW
    email = u2.email,
    first_name = u2.first_name,
    last_name = u2.last_name
    from (values
   (1, 'hollis@weimann.biz', 'Hollis', 'O\'Connell'),
   (2, 'robert@duncan.info', 'Robert', 'Duncan')
    ) as u2(id, email, first_name, last_name)
    where u2.id = u.id;
```

Above query is used to update multiple rows in one query and it works efficiently as well but I have a JSON below:

```
   Person:{[id:1,email:"[xyz@abc.com]",first_name:"John",last_name:"Doe"],[id:2,email:"[xyz@abc.com]",first_name:"Robert",last_name:"Duncan"],[id:3,email:"[xyz@abc.com]",first_name:"Ram",last_name:"Das"],[id:4,email:"[xyz@abc.com]",first_name:"Albert",last_name:"Pinto"],[id:5,email:"[xyz@abc.com]",first_name:"Robert",last_name:"Peter"],[id:6,email:"[xyz@abc.com]",first_name:"Christian",last_name:"Lint"],[id:7,email:"[xyz@abc.com]",first_name:"Mike",last_name:"Hussey"],[id:8,email:"[xyz@abc.com]",first_name:"Ralph",last_name:"Hunter"]};
```

Such JSON has 1000 data which I want to insert in the Database using JPA. Currently I have inserted it by iterating this which makes my code slow,Is there any other alternative which can be implemented.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my Java Code :

```
     public Boolean multiEditPerson(List<PersonList> personList) {

        for (PersonList list : personList) {
            Person personMstr = em.find(Person.class, list.getId());
            personMstr.setFirstName(list.getFirstName());
            personMstr.setLastName(list.getLastName());
            personMstr.setEmail(Arrays.toString(list.getEmail()));
            em.persist(personMstr);
        }
        return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

Comment: show java code.

Comment: Please the above code for reference. - @Jacek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a bulk insert based on the json document. You should reformat the document as the format shown in the question is strange and unpractical.

Full working example:

```
create table example(id int primary key, email text, last_name text, first_name text);

with jsondata(jdata) as (
    values
    (
    '[
        {"id": 1, "email": "[xyz@abc.com]", "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe"},
        {"id": 2, "email": "[xyz@abc.com]", "first_name": "Robert", "last_name": "Duncan"},
        {"id": 3, "email": "[xyz@abc.com]", "first_name": "Ram", "last_name": "Das"},
        {"id": 4, "email": "[xyz@abc.com]", "first_name": "Albert", "last_name": "Pinto"},
        {"id": 5, "email": "[xyz@abc.com]", "first_name": "Robert", "last_name": "Peter"},
        {"id": 6, "email": "[xyz@abc.com]", "first_name": "Christian", "last_name": "Lint"},
        {"id": 7, "email": "[xyz@abc.com]", "first_name": "Mike", "last_name": "Hussey"},
        {"id": 8, "email": "[xyz@abc.com]", "first_name": "Ralph", "last_name": "Hunter"}
    ]'::jsonb)
)

insert into example 
select (elem->>'id')::int, elem->>'email', elem->>'last_name', elem->>'first_name'
from jsondata,
jsonb_array_elements(jdata) as elem;
```

The result:

```
select *
from example

 id |     email     | last_name | first_name 
----+---------------+-----------+------------
  1 | [xyz@abc.com] | Doe       | John
  2 | [xyz@abc.com] | Duncan    | Robert
  3 | [xyz@abc.com] | Das       | Ram
  4 | [xyz@abc.com] | Pinto     | Albert
  5 | [xyz@abc.com] | Peter     | Robert
  6 | [xyz@abc.com] | Lint      | Christian
  7 | [xyz@abc.com] | Hussey    | Mike
  8 | [xyz@abc.com] | Hunter    | Ralph
(8 rows)
```

---

If you want to update the table (instead of insert into it):

```
with jsondata(jdata) as (
    -- values as above
)

update example set
    email = elem->>'email', 
    last_name = elem->>'last_name', 
    first_name = elem->>'first_name'
from jsondata,
jsonb_array_elements(jdata) as elem
where id = (elem->>'id')::int;
```

Comment: I tried this example which helped me in creating a temporary table and updating my master table. Updating multiple columns from temp table to master table.Can you please confirm if this is what I should use in JPA or something else I need to do research on.

Comment: You can also do an update directly, without a temporary buffer. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to do a patch insertion without commit for each record. If this is a one time job, it is better to process it on the PostgreSQL side, insert the Json entries all at once to the database using unlogged table and  then update you main table.

here an exmaple from documentation to change a json to rwos

```
select * from json_each('{"a":"foo", "b":"bar"}')
```

if this is not one time job, you need to create a batch insert in your java code. Do not process one person at a time but the whole list of persons.

Comment: I am not java expert and I can not tell if the code is good or not , but here a small article http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.de/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply to everyone !!

I have used below query to update records using JSON directly in the db.

```
    UPDATE person p
                SET (first_name,email,last_name)= 
                (COALESCE(ab.first_name, p.first_name)
                , COALESCE(ab.email,p.email)
                ,COALESCE(ab.last_name, p.last_name)
                     )
                FROM (
                  select * from  json_populate_recordset 
                (null::person,'[{"id":1,"first_name":"Robert","email":"robert.stark@xyz.com","last_name":"Stark"},{"id":2,"first_name":"John","email":"John.Doe@xyz.com","last_name":"Doe"}]')
                  ) ab
                WHERE p.id = ab.id;
```