# How to update table based on a json map?

Tags: database, postgresql

If I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (
    a integer,
    b integer,
    c text
);
INSERT INTO tmp (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 'foo');
```

And this json:

```
{
    "a": 4,
    "c": "bar"
}
```

Where the keys map to the column names, and the values are the new values.

How can I update the `tmp` table without touching columns that aren't in the map?

I thought about constructing a dynamic string of SQL `update` statement that can be executed in pl/pgsql, but it seems the number of arguments that get passed to `USING` must be predetermined. But the actual number of arguments is determined by the number of keys in the map, which is dynamic, so this seems like a dead end.

I know I can update the table using multiple update statements as I loop over the keys, but the problem is that I have a trigger set up for the table that will revision the table (by inserting changed columns into another table), so the columns must be updated in a single `update` statement.

I wonder if it's possible to dynamically update a table with a json map?

Comment: [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45745845/1995738).

Comment: @klin thanks, but not sure if it works, If I simply extract all possible keys from the map, in my example, `(map->>'b')::integer` would return `null`, and in the update statement, wouldn't it update `b` with `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [coalesce()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL). Example table:

```
drop table if exists my_table;
create table my_table(id int primary key, a int, b text, c date);
insert into my_table values (1, 1, 'old text', '2017-01-01');
```

and query:

```
with jsondata(jdata) as (
    values ('{"id": 1, "b": "new text"}'::jsonb)
)

update my_table set
    a = coalesce((jdata->>'a')::int, a),
    b = coalesce((jdata->>'b')::text, b),
    c = coalesce((jdata->>'c')::date, c)
from jsondata
where id = (jdata->>'id')::int;

select * from my_table;

 id | a |    b     |     c      
----+---+----------+------------
  1 | 1 | new text | 2017-01-01
(1 row)
```

Comment: A bit more general solution: `update my_table set (a, b, c) = (select a, b, c from jsonb_populate_record(null::my_table, to_jsonb(my_table) || jdata)) ...`